# comparision between nsmutablearray.count & tableview indexpath.row is giving odd results

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison

I have below.

```
NSLog(@"aaaa===%ld==%ld", indexPath.row, (rowsOptionss.count-1));

if (indexPath.row>(rowsOptionss.count-1)) {
    NSLog(@"000===this is true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"000===this is false");
}

if (0>-1) {
    NSLog(@"001===this is true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"001===this is false");
}
```

This is giving me result as below.

```
2016-02-04 13:02:15.316 ClubsFans[7085:16944474] aaaa===0==-1
2016-02-04 13:02:15.316 ClubsFans[7085:16944474] 000===this is false
2016-02-04 13:02:15.316 ClubsFans[7085:16944474] 001===this is true
```

I was expected to say

```
2016-02-04 13:02:15.316 ClubsFans[7085:16944474] aaaa===0==-1
2016-02-04 13:02:15.316 ClubsFans[7085:16944474] 000===this is true >> this should be true
2016-02-04 13:02:15.316 ClubsFans[7085:16944474] 001===this is true
```

***Any idea why this is going wrong?***

Comment: unsigned integer underflow. With unsigned integers it's always safer to add than to subtract, e.g. `indexPath.row + 1 < rowOptions.count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this may help you to understand:

```
NSIndexPath* indexPath = nil;
NSArray * rowsOptionss = [NSArray array];
NSLog(@"aaaa===%ld==%ld", indexPath.row, (rowsOptionss.count-1));
NSLog(@"real value: bbbb===%ld==%u", (long)indexPath.row, (rowsOptionss.count-1));

if (indexPath.row>(rowsOptionss.count-1)) {
    NSLog(@"000===this is true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"000===this is false");
}

if (0>-1) {
    NSLog(@"001===this is true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"001===this is false");
}
```

`rowsOptionss.count` is unsigned `(NSUInteger)` and if you do a `-1` operation you'll get a very big positive number, that is always bigger than 0.

that's the log:

```
 aaaa===0==-1
 real value: bbbb===0==4294967295
 000===this is false
 001===this is true
```

if you need a signed int, use this instead:

```
NSInteger tempInt = rowsOptionss.count;
tempInt --;
LOG(@"tempInt %i", tempInt);
```

Comment: I would recommend to print integer numbers using `"%@"` and `@(rowsOptionss.count-1))`

Answer (score 0):

@Fahim Parkar

Please try to convert from **NSInteger** to **Int**.  It might cause of comparing `NSInteger`.

> if((int) indexPath.row > (int)(rowsOptionss.count-1))

Hope this will help you.